# Excluding peer dependency for react-native only

Tags: react-native, webpack

I'm currently working on two packages:

- One contains common JS features to be used in multiple packages (web, native). Although, it uses some modules that should be available in web environment only (e.g. sweetalert2).
- The other one is a react-native app that uses some of the features exported by the common package.

I would like to exclude the "sweetalert2" module from the building process conditionally. It means that I would like it to be included when compiling one of my web apps using the common package, but *NOT* included when importing the common package by a native app.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You can use Platform module of react native that can be use to distinguish code for web and RN app.
Platform.os gives 'android' or 'ios' values, so this can help you to import files dynamicaly for web or RN app.
You can get further refernce for Platform from react-native docs
[PLATFORM REACT NATIVE](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code.html)

Comment: Question is about separating web and react-native projects builds from each other. Platform module is for separating react-native code for different operating system.

Comment: You can also use it to seperate web and rn code.
You can save your files as 
abc.js for web
And abc.native.js for rn app.
This will also distinguish btw web and app.

Comment: OP wants to separate files in build process not runtime.

Comment: @bennygenel: Exactly, I would like to separate them in the build process. I tried to add:
`"react-native": {
"sweetalert2": false
}`
into package.json, but didn't work.